# Should I initialize a List when declaring it or should I use a static block?

Tags: java

Could anyone explain which one of the two snippets below would be best practice for initializing a `static final List`?

**Initialize when declaring:**

```
public class Sample {

   private static final List<String> myList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
            "Cache-Control",
            "Content-Language",
            "Content-Type",
            "Expires",
            "Last-Modified",
            "Pragma"
    ));
}
```

**Initialize in static block:**

```
public class Sample {

   private static final List<String> myList;

   static { 
    myList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
            "Cache-Control",
            "Content-Language",
            "Content-Type",
            "Expires",
            "Last-Modified",
            "Pragma"
    ));
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference.  Use the one you think is clearer.

Comment: Btw: `static final` member names should be ALL_CAPS.

Comment: Just stay consistent with the one you use. i.e. always initialize static fields in the same way.

Comment: @MartinSchröder To my knowledge this is only true for real Constants and not references.

Comment: @Diyarbakir: You create an `unmodifiableList`. There's nothing non-constant here. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initialize variables where they are declared if possible. It reduces the memory load on the reader. "Ah, here's a list of ..." as opposed to "Here's a list... and here's the initialization." Even if they are adjacent, using static initialization increases the amount of code to be read. Bit by bit the verbosity adds up and makes maintenance more expensive.

Save static initialization for cases where it is required, e.g. preloading a Map.

Comment: I agree, less code is usually better, as long as readability is not sacrificed, which in my opinion, it is not here.  Though that is personal preference, I admit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to avoid `static` blocks wherever possible for the reasons [mentioned](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/314923/164151) by [kevin cline](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/16929/kevin-cline). If initializing the field with a simple expression is not possible, I prefer to factor the logic out into a `private` `static` helper method. It is very clear about the intent, keeps the declaration of your fields compact and works in almost any case I've seen so far.

```java
private static final Map<Integer, String> daysOfTheWeek = makeDaysOfWeek();

private static Map<Integer, String> makeDaysOfWeek() {
    final Map<Integer, String> days = new TreeMap<>();
    days.put(0, "Monday");
    days.put(1, "Tuesday");
    days.put(2, "Wednesday");
    days.put(3, "Thursday");
    days.put(4, "Friday");
    days.put(5, "Saturday");
    days.put(6, "Sunday");
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(days);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**It makes no difference and it's a matter of personal preference.**

**That said I like the second option best** because the initialization, not being a one-liner, breaks the visual tidyness when there are several members.

For example:

```
private int foo=0;
private static final List<String> myList;
private int bar=1;
private int baz=3;

static { 
 myList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
         "Cache-Control",
         "Content-Language",
         "Content-Type",
         "Expires",
         "Last-Modified",
         "Pragma"
 ));
}
```

is tidier than

```
private int foo=0;
private static final List<String> myList= Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
                     "Cache-Control",
                     "Content-Language",
                     "Content-Type",
                     "Expires",
                     "Last-Modified",
                     "Pragma"
                 ));
private int bar=1;
private int baz=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

A key point of this is that the list is final. If your variable is final, unless there are multiple static methods for initialization, you should initialize it at the same time that you declare it. This limits overhead. Both ways work, but in this case keeping it simple keeps it memory efficient.